# Gas Estimation Error - Swap Contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, gas-limit, uniswap, kovan

I'm working on developing a contract that automatically performs a swap and have been having an issue with the swap function. I finally got the contract deployed on Kovan, but have been getting the same gas estimation error whenever I try to call "Token Swap" through remix.

Right now for my inputs I have WETH to DAI. Putting in 1 WETH, putting in 1 ETH in the value section on remix, and have 3000000 gas limit selected. The goal is to have it sent to the same contract calling it

When I call the function, I get the following warning: "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
The execution failed due to an exception. Reverted"

I've messed with the inputs for hours, would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is the most recent failed TX: https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x263c5fb1470962208b1aa812a376a2c934e80d351c7d45bd8a07a7ecce1d4734

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;


//import the ERC20 interface

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint amount
    ) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}


//import the uniswap router
//the contract needs to use swapExactTokensForTokens
//this will allow us to import swapExactTokensForTokens into our contract

interface IUniswapV2Router {
  function getAmountsOut(uint256 amountIn, address[] memory path)
    external
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
  
  function swapExactTokensForTokens(
  
    //amount of tokens we are sending in
    uint256 amountIn,
    //the minimum amount of tokens we want out of the trade
    uint256 amountOutMin,
    //list of token addresses we are going to trade in.  this is necessary to calculate amounts
    address[] calldata path,
    //this is the address we are going to send the output tokens to
    address to,
    //the last time that the trade is valid for
    uint256 deadline
  ) external returns (uint256[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
  function token0() external view returns (address);
  function token1() external view returns (address);
  function swap(
    uint256 amount0Out,
    uint256 amount1Out,
    address to,
    bytes calldata data
  ) external;
}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
  function getPair(address token0, address token1) external returns (address);
}



contract tokenSwap {
    
    //address of the uniswap v2 router
    address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    
    
    address private WETH = 0xd0A1E359811322d97991E03f863a0C30C2cF029C;
    address private DAI = 0x1528F3FCc26d13F7079325Fb78D9442607781c8C;
    address private USDT = 0x2F375e94FC336Cdec2Dc0cCB5277FE59CBf1cAe5;

   
    
   function swap(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn, uint256 _amountOutMin, address _to) external {
  
    
    IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, _amountIn);

    address[] memory path;
    if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
      path = new address[](2);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = _tokenOut;
    } else {
      path = new address[](3);
      path[0] = _tokenIn;
      path[1] = WETH;
      path[2] = _tokenOut;
    }
        
        IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, _amountOutMin, path, _to, block.timestamp);
    }
    
      
     function getAmountOutMin(address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amountIn) external view returns (uint256) {

       
        address[] memory path;
        if (_tokenIn == WETH || _tokenOut == WETH) {
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = _tokenOut;
        } else {
            path = new address[](3);
            path[0] = _tokenIn;
            path[1] = WETH;
            path[2] = _tokenOut;
        }
        
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
        return amountOutMins[path.length -1];
    
    }
    
    // important to receive ETH
    receive() payable external {}
}
```